# fluent-ffmpeg failed with zero output or errors

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, wav, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm attempting to convert a `.webm` audio file to a `.wav` audio file using fluent-ffmpeg. I've looked through all kinds of example code, but whenever I run my code I get no output or errors whatsoever:

```
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';

function verifyAudio({ testFile }) {

    // parse file name for wav file from testFile
    const wavFile = testFile.split('.')[0] + '.wav';
    console.log(`wavFile: ${wavFile}`);

    // convert to wav file
    ffmpeg(testFile)
        .inputFormat('webm')
        .outputFormat('wav')
        .on('start', function(commandLine) {
            console.log('Spawned Ffmpeg with command: ' + commandLine);
        })
        .on('progress', (progress) => {
            console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
        })
        .on('end', function(err) {
            console.log('done!', err);
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('an error: ' + err);
        }).saveToFile(wavFile);
    console.log('finished conversion');
}

export { verifyAudio };
```

This function takes in the name of the input `.webm` file as an argument, and attempts to convert it to a `.wav` file with filename `wavFile`. When this runs, I see the output of `console.log(`wavFile: ${wavFile}`);`, I see the output of `console.log('finished conversion');`, but none of the `.on` outputs in the `ffmpeg` call. No errors are raised at all. Not even when I insert a non-existent filename as `testFile`. And no output file is generated (not even an empty one).

I have no idea what's going on here, since I have no output to debug on! What is happening here?

I've tried many combinations of defining inputs and outputs, including the various formats. I've tried doing the conversion on the command line using `ffmpeg`, it it works fine.

I'm expecting to see the output file: A `.wav` file with the filename `wavFile`. I see nothing.

Comment: The conversion process in `fluent-ffmpeg` is asynchronous. This means the line `console.log('finished conversion')` might be executed before the conversion actually finishes. This could lead to confusion, as it implies the process is complete when it may not be.

Comment: @ImanMohammadi Yes, I understand, but the output file never appears even after some delay, nor does the `console.log` statement for `.on('start')` ever display. Could it be that this needs to be run inside a promise?